# Find the furthest y cartesian coordinate for 6 DoF robot in joint coordinates

Tags: optimization, robotics, inverse-kinematics

I've got robotic arm with 6 DoF. I make constrain that x, z carteasian coordinate and orientation is exactly specified. I would like to get joint coordinates which are at cartesian position [x, y_max, z], where y_max is the maximum y cartesian coordinate which is reachable by the end-effector of the robotic arm.

For example:
I set x to be 0.5, z to by 1.0 and I want to find joint coordinates that satisfy after forward kinematics that robot's end-effector is at cartesian coordinates [0.5, maximum reachable coordinate, 1.0].

I know that if I know cartesian position and orientation I can find joint coordinates by inverse kinematics and check if the end-effector is at desired coordinateds by forward kinematics, but what if I don't know one of the axis in cartesian and it depends on robot how far it is possible to move? As far as I know, inverse kinematics is possible to solve analyticaly or numericaly, but to solve it I need to know the whole frame of the finish coordinate.

Moreover I would like to have orientation dependent on y coordinate. (for example I would like to guarantee that end-effector is always looking at coordinates [0.5, 0, 0]).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a numerical [task-based inverse kinematics](https://scaron.info/robotics/inverse-kinematics.html) with a task such as:

- Orientation: the orientation you have specified
- Position in (x, z): the coordinates you have specified
- Position in y: something very far away

The behavior of a task-based approach (with proper damping) when a target is not feasible is to "stretch" the robot as far as it can without violating its constraints. Here is an example with a humanoid robot and three tasks:

[image: IK solution when tasks are not feasible]

> (for example I would like to guarantee that end-effector is always looking at coordinates [0.5, 0, 0])

This should be possible with a proper task as well. For example, in C++ the mc_rtc framework has a [LookAtTask](https://jrl-umi3218.github.io/mc_rtc/doxygen-html/structmc__tasks_1_1LookAtTask.html) to keep a frame looking at a desired point.